# Faulty Installed Clock Triggers on an Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack-api, add-on

I designed a rather simple Add-On to enable my local team to more easily automate newsletters and target updates to Slack.

The Add-On works well, aside from two issues:

1. **Schedule a send functionality.**

I'm using the ScriptApp's newTrigger() function to allow users to schedule automatic sends.
While it seemed to have worked in original tests, the triggers are now triggering at the wrong time (a trigger that should run daily from 11-12AM has been running at 5PM - Another that should run at 6PM has been running at 12AM - I've checked and the timezones appear to be correct GMT+2 for Paris)

2. **GetActive() returning the wrong sheet**

This is a minor problem as I've only noticed it twice, but when running a script with getActive() from the correct sheet, it accidentally ran the script using another spreadsheet.

I remain at your disposal should you need any more information, IDs or the likes.

Thank you for any help and have a fantastic day

Comment: Is this a Sheets add-on?  The actual trigger time seems to be 6 hours difference from the set time.  And the actual trigger time seems to be ahead of the set time.  The add-on runs in the time zone set in your Apps Script project, it doesn't use the time zone of the user account that installed the add-on.  Any time that a date calculation is made, the Apps Script JavaScript will use the time zone of the script to adjust the time.  Do your users have a different time zone than your time zone?  Are you setting/retrieving dates from a Sheet cell?  The time zone in the Sheet can adjust the time.

Comment: Also, are you using runtime V8?  V8 has caused some trigger failures.  I don't know if that's related to your issue, but I'd thought I'd mention it.  If what you are experiencing is a bug, then you'd need a way to reproduce the issue, to prove it's really a bug, rather than your mistake.

Comment: In addition to what @AlanWells asked, keep in mind getActive() returns the currently active spreadsheet meaning this will open the one which your Apps script is bound, is your code bound to the Spreadsheet you are trying to open? Otherwise you should consider to change the method to [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid).